# Getting error while running gulp from cmd in laravel application

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

while running gulp from cmd

module.js:328                                                                       throw err;                                                                      ^

> Error: Cannot find module 'dateformat'
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
>   at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>   at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>   at Object.
>   (C:\Users\Npandey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-util\index.js:5:9)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>   at Module.require (module.js:354:17)

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes i did run npm install

Answer (score 1):

Npm install worked for me. I had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules folder and again  **npm install**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13407785)

Comment: I answered it. Cant you see i asked him to remove node_modules folder and then run command npm install